# Python BasicConfig Logging does not change logfile

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I wrote a small function to log events to a file. This python script is imported in the main script. The mainscript runs as a daemon (actually it is polling a database).

MainScript.py:

```
import logger

logger.logmessage(module = module, message = "SomeMessage")
```

logger.py:

```
def logmessage(message, module, level = 'INFO'):
    today = str(datetime.date.today())
    logFile = '/path/to/log/myapplog.'+today+'.log'

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - '+ module + ' -  %(message)s',level=logging.INFO,filename=logFile)

    if level is "INFO":
        logging.info(message)
    elif level is "WARNING":
        logging.warning(message)
    elif level is "CRITICAL":
        logging.critical(message)
```

My intention: get logfiles like myapplog.2014-01-23.log, 2014-01-24.log, ...

My proplem: the logfile stays the same. It constantly logs to myapplog.2014-01-23.log and only after a restart of the daemon, the proper log with correct date is created and used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use `TimedRotatingFileHandler` as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler).

Also, you shouldn't call `basicConfig()` more than once (I presume you're calling `logmessage` more than once). As [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig), basicConfig() won't do anything except set up a basic configuration if there is none (so only the first call does anything - subsequent calls find there is a configuration, so don't do anything).